# Error hiding markers on google map javascript api zoom 3.7

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have a map with 3 icons zoomed in to street level, and would like the 2nd and 3rd to disappear when the map is zoomed out. They merge together otherwise...

I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError and am having trouble resolving it.  The console says markers[y].setVisible is not a function.

I've tried a few things, like moving the code into the event handlers for clicks and changing to marker.setVisible(false) instead of markers[y].setVisible(z<=15). This doesn't result in console errors, but doesn't make the icons disappear either.

```
function initMaps () { 
        $.getScript("//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&v=3.7", function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                insertBefore = head.insertBefore;

            head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
                if (newElement.href && newElement.href.indexOf('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') !== -1 || newElement.innerHTML.indexOf('gm-style') !== -1) {
                    return;
                }
                insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
            };
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            for (var i = 0; i < plugins.maps.length; i++) {
                var zoom = parseInt(plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-zoom"), 15) || 16;
                var styles = plugins.maps[i].hasAttribute('data-styles') ? JSON.parse(plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-styles")) : [];
                var center = plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-center") || "New York";

                // Initialize map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(plugins.maps[i].querySelectorAll(".google-map")[0], {
                    zoom: zoom,
                    styles: styles,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
                });
                // Add map object to map node
                plugins.maps[i].map = map;
                plugins.maps[i].geocoder = geocoder;
                plugins.maps[i].google = google;

                // Get Center coordinates from attribute
                getLatLngObject(center, null, plugins.maps[i], function (location, markerElement, mapElement) {
                    mapElement.map.setCenter(location);
                })

                // Add markers from google-map-markers array
                var markerItems = plugins.maps[i].querySelectorAll(".google-map-markers li");

                if (markerItems.length){
                    var markers = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < markerItems.length; j++){
                        var markerElement = markerItems[j];
                        getLatLngObject(markerElement.getAttribute("data-location"), markerElement, plugins.maps[i], function(location, markerElement, mapElement){
                            var icon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon");
                            var activeIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active");
                            var info = markerElement.getAttribute("data-description") || "";
                            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: info
                            });
                            markerElement.infoWindow = infoWindow;
                            var markerData = {
                                position: location,
                                map: mapElement.map
                            }
                            if (icon){
                                markerData.icon = icon;
                            }
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerData);

                            markerElement.gmarker = marker;
                            markers.push({markerElement: markerElement, infoWindow: infoWindow});
                            marker.isActive = false;

                            // THIS WORKS marker.setVisible(false);

                            // Handle infoWindow close click
                            google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',(function(markerElement, mapElement){
                                var markerIcon = null;
                                markerElement.gmarker.isActive = false;
                                markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon");
                                markerElement.gmarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                            }).bind(this, markerElement, mapElement));                          

                            // Set marker active on Click and open infoWindow
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(markerElement, mapElement) {
                                if (markerElement.infoWindow.getContent().length === 0) return;
                                var gMarker, currentMarker = markerElement.gmarker, currentInfoWindow;
                                for (var k =0; k < markers.length; k++){
                                    var markerIcon;
                                    if (markers[k].markerElement === markerElement){
                                        currentInfoWindow = markers[k].infoWindow;
                                    }
                                    gMarker = markers[k].markerElement.gmarker;
                                    if (gMarker.isActive && markers[k].markerElement !== markerElement){
                                        gMarker.isActive = false;
                                        markerIcon = markers[k].markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon")
                                        gMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                        markers[k].infoWindow.close();
                                    }
                                }

                                currentMarker.isActive = !currentMarker.isActive;
                                if (currentMarker.isActive) {
                                    if (markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active")){
                                        currentMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                    }

                                    currentInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                }else{
                                    if (markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon")){
                                        currentMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                    }
                                    currentInfoWindow.close();
                                }
                            }).bind(this, markerElement, mapElement))       
                        })
                    }

                    /* NOT WORKING
                    /* Change markers on zoom */
                    /*zoom 0 is whole earth, 10 city, 15 streets */
                    map.addListener('zoom_changed',function(){
                            var z = map.getZoom();
                            // iterate over markers and call setVisible
                            for (var y = 1; y < markerItems.length; y++) {
                                    markers[y].setVisible(z <= 15);
                            }                                   
                    }); 

                }                       
            }                           
        });             
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The markers array had both marker and infowindow components.  A new array populated with just marker components is the correct object for the setVisible property.

```
    function initMaps () { 
        $.getScript("//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&v=3.7", function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                insertBefore = head.insertBefore;

            head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
                if (newElement.href && newElement.href.indexOf('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') !== -1 || newElement.innerHTML.indexOf('gm-style') !== -1) {
                    return;
                }
                insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
            };
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            for (var i = 0; i < plugins.maps.length; i++) {
                var zoom = parseInt(plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-zoom"), 15) || 16;
                var styles = plugins.maps[i].hasAttribute('data-styles') ? JSON.parse(plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-styles")) : [];
                var center = plugins.maps[i].getAttribute("data-center") || "New York";

                // Initialize map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(plugins.maps[i].querySelectorAll(".google-map")[0], {
                    zoom: zoom,
                    styles: styles,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
                });
                // Add map object to map node
                plugins.maps[i].map = map;
                plugins.maps[i].geocoder = geocoder;
                plugins.maps[i].google = google;

                // Get Center coordinates from attribute
                getLatLngObject(center, null, plugins.maps[i], function (location, markerElement, mapElement) {
                    mapElement.map.setCenter(location);
                })

                // Add markers from google-map-markers array
                var markerItems = plugins.maps[i].querySelectorAll(".google-map-markers li");

                if (markerItems.length){
                    var markers = [];
                    var m = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < markerItems.length; j++){
                        var markerElement = markerItems[j];
                        getLatLngObject(markerElement.getAttribute("data-location"), markerElement, plugins.maps[i], function(location, markerElement, mapElement){
                            var icon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon");
                            var activeIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active");
                            var info = markerElement.getAttribute("data-description") || "";
                            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: info
                            });
                            markerElement.infoWindow = infoWindow;
                            var markerData = {
                                position: location,
                                map: mapElement.map
                            }
                            if (icon){
                                markerData.icon = icon;
                            }
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerData);

                            markerElement.gmarker = marker;
                            markers.push({markerElement: markerElement, infoWindow: infoWindow});
                            marker.isActive = false;

                            m.push(marker);

                            // THIS WORKS marker.setVisible(false);                     

                            // Handle infoWindow close click
                            google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',(function(markerElement, mapElement){
                                var markerIcon = null;
                                markerElement.gmarker.isActive = false;
                                markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon");
                                markerElement.gmarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                            }).bind(this, markerElement, mapElement));                          

                            // Set marker active on Click and open infoWindow
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(markerElement, mapElement) {
                                if (markerElement.infoWindow.getContent().length === 0) return;
                                var gMarker, currentMarker = markerElement.gmarker, currentInfoWindow;
                                for (var k =0; k < markers.length; k++){
                                    var markerIcon;
                                    if (markers[k].markerElement === markerElement){
                                        currentInfoWindow = markers[k].infoWindow;
                                    }
                                    gMarker = markers[k].markerElement.gmarker;
                                    if (gMarker.isActive && markers[k].markerElement !== markerElement){
                                        gMarker.isActive = false;
                                        markerIcon = markers[k].markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon")
                                        gMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                        markers[k].infoWindow.close();
                                    }
                                }

                                currentMarker.isActive = !currentMarker.isActive;
                                if (currentMarker.isActive) {
                                    if (markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon-active")){
                                        currentMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                    }

                                    currentInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                }else{
                                    if (markerIcon = markerElement.getAttribute("data-icon") || mapElement.getAttribute("data-icon")){
                                        currentMarker.setIcon(markerIcon);
                                    }
                                    currentInfoWindow.close();
                                }
                            }).bind(this, markerElement, mapElement))       
                        })
                    }

                    /* Change markers on zoom */
                    /*zoom 0 is whole earth, 10 city, 15 streets */

                    map.addListener('zoom_changed',function(){
                            var z = map.getZoom();
                            // iterate over markers and call setVisible
                            for (var y = 1; y < markerItems.length; y++) {
                                    m[y].setVisible(z >= 15);
                            }                           
                    }); 

                }                       
            }                           
        });             
    }
```